Windows Overlapped I/O with IOCP and FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING is exceptionally slow in random 4K scenario
I am developing an asynchronous I/O framework for Windows LLM inference. Suppose I have 8 threads executing computation tasks. When a computation task finds that the required neurons for the next stage are not in the memory pool, the computation thread places the task closure into the I/O queue. An I/O thread then retrieves it, allocates a buffer from the memory pool using a lock-free LRU, and generates a series of I/O closures (usually hundreds for each task) containing the buffer, size, and offset, which are then placed into the I/O execution queue.
My asynchronous I/O framework needs to fetch tasks from this I/O execution queue, complete the I/O, modify atomic variables, and once all I/O operations are complete, the task is placed back into the computation queue to continue execution. Below is my asynchronous I/O framework:
static inline bool check_complete(HANDLE hCompletionPort, bool wait) {
    DWORD bytesTransferred;
    ULONG_PTR completionKey;
    LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped;

    BOOL result = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, &bytesTransferred, &completionKey,
                                                &lpOverlapped, wait? INFINITE: 1);
    if (result) {
        struct iocb *iocb_task = CONTAINING_RECORD(lpOverlapped, struct iocb, overlap);
        finished += 1; // atomic
        free(iocb_task->buffer); free(iocb_task);
        return true; // get a completed IO closure
    }
    return false;
}

static inline bool do_read(HANDLE hFile, bool wait) {
    iocb_t *iocb_task = NULL;
    if (wait) {
        iocb_task = (iocb_t *)queue_wait_and_pop_ptr(&queue);
    } else {
        iocb_task = (iocb_t *)queue_try_pop_ptr(&queue);
        if (iocb_task == NULL) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    BOOL result = ReadFile(hFile, iocb_task->buffer, iocb_task->size, NULL, &iocb_task->overlap);
    if (result) {
        finished += 1; // atomic
        free(iocb_task->buffer); free(iocb_task);
        return false;
    } else {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) { // ...
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}

DWORD WINAPI prepare_io(LPVOID param) {
    int key = (int)param, ioPending = 0;

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA( // over *60G*, large file
        TARGET_FILE_PATH, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);
    
    HANDLE hCompletionPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(hFile, NULL, 0, 1);

    while (true) {
        while (ioPending > NUM_QUEUE_SIZE) { // max queue
            check_complete(hCompletionPort, true);
            --ioPending;
        }
        if (ioPending == 0) {
            do_read(hFile, true);
            ++ioPending;
        } else {
            if (do_read(hFile, false))
                ++ioPending;
            if (check_complete(hCompletionPort, false))
                --ioPending;
        }
    }
    // close ...
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    HANDLE ioThreads[NUM_IO_THREADS]; // 16 threads and 64 queue size
    queue_init(&queue, NUM_QUEUE_SIZE * NUM_IO_THREADS);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IO_THREADS; ++i) {
        ioThreads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 64 * 1024, prepare_io, (LPVOID)i, 0, NULL);
    }

    LONGLONG totalRequests = TOTAL_DATA_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE;
    DWORD startTime = GetTickCount();

    for (LONGLONG i = 0; i < totalRequests; i++) {
        char *buffer = (char *)malloc(BLOCK_SIZE);
        iocb_t *iocb = (iocb_t *)malloc(sizeof(iocb_t));
        memset(iocb, 0, sizeof(iocb_t));

        LONGLONG offset = ((LONGLONG)rand() * rand()) % (fileInfo.nFileSizeLow - BLOCK_SIZE);
        offset = (offset / BLOCK_SIZE) * BLOCK_SIZE; // Align to 4K

        iocb->buffer = buffer;
        iocb->overlap.Offset = offset & 0xFFFFFFFF;
        iocb->overlap.OffsetHigh = offset >> 32;
        iocb->size = BLOCK_SIZE;
        queue_push(&queue, iocb);
    }

    while (finished < totalRequests) {
    }

    DWORD endTime = GetTickCount();
    DWORD totalTime = endTime - startTime;

    printf("Total time: %lu ms\n", totalTime);
    printf("Average throughput: %.2f MB/s\n", (double)TOTAL_DATA_SIZE / (1024 * 1024) / (totalTime / 1000.0));
    
    queue_destroy(&queue);
    return 0;
}

Above I/O framework can achieve 2.6GB/s in my SSD. It's  The throughput matches the actual performance of the disk.
However, when I ported this framework to the pipeline I mentioned earlier, the performance was only 50MB/s. The performance difference between the framework microbenchmark and the real scenario is 50 times, but the target file, number of threads, queue depth, and code are exactly the same.
Here are some of my observations:

Reducing the number of I/O threads to 1 still results in only 50MB/s, indicating that it is not caused by a conflict between I/O threads and computation threads.
The queue implementation uses locks and condition variables, and the same code is used in both the microbenchmark and the real scenario.
Removing FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING results in 1100MB/s, indicating that the bottleneck is not in the queue's I/O closure.

Does anyone have any good suggestions?

@EugeneMayevski'Callback Thanks for your attention. I have a LRU memory pool so there's no need to use fs cache, and use directio helps us make full use of concurrent read throughput of SSD, avoid cache-layer conflict.

because you not set FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS than if ReadFile return true (I/O completed synchronous) - will be packet queued to IOCP in this case to, so you have wrong logic after ReadFile call. and your loop logic. async I/O must be handled in another way, without any loops. ( GetQueuedCompletionStatus how called also wrong - in case I/O finished with error) - you create thread pool, which wait on IOCP and handle it, or better use BindIoCompletionCallback or CreateThreadpoolIo (TpAllocIoCompletion) and not need by self any CreateThread, GetQueuedCompletionStatus

@RbMm I don't think so. I have tried CreateThreadpoolIo, but when only one thread opens one hFile handle, the throughput is less than 1GB/s. I believe that having multiple threads open multiple hFile handles helps to avoid contention at the fs-level and maximizes disk IO speed.

because you open file in asynchronous mode, no matter how many different FILE_OBJECTs you create on file. so not need more than 1. if you have more bad result in this case - due not efficient code only (i not view your code)

@RbMm use multiple threads to send ReadFile requests does improve i/o throughput, if I use 16 threads (whether use CreateThreadpoolIo or GetQueuedCompletionStatus), I achieve 2.6GB/s, but if use 1 thread, only 700MB/s. In fact, the microbenchmark I used above perf IS 2.6G/s, but when ported, only 50MB/s. Thank for your advice!

use multiple threads to send ReadFile requests != use multiple file handles. of course if disk have no seek penalty - we can use multiple reads at once and this will be faster compare single read. but this not related to use I/O calbacks (thread pool) - you can use this in any case.
